# xml queries with exist and contains giving unexpected results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, xml, xquery

I have a query as shown below.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE  
(   
 id INT,    
 col XML        
)   
INSERT INTO @tbl    
VALUES  
(1,'<Root>
  <Row>
    <User>xyz</User>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Maxrowid>1</Maxrowid>
</Root>'),
(2,'<Root>
  <Row>
    <User>xyz</User>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <User>mnj</User>
    <Rowid>2</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Maxrowid>2</Maxrowid>
</Root>'),(3,'<Root>
  <Row>
    <User>abs</User>
    <Rowid>1</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <User>xra</User>
    <Rowid>2</Rowid>
  </Row>
  <Maxrowid>2</Maxrowid>
</Root>
')  

--table before---
SELECT  *
FROM    @tbl t1
------------------

DECLARE @id varchar 
SELECT @id = 'xyz'  
SELECT  *   
FROM    @tbl t1 
WHERE col.exist('//*/text()[contains(.,sql:variable("@id"))]') = 1
```

I am expecting this query to output rows which has 'xyz' in xml column 'col' anywhere. But it returns all rows.(when i checked it returns all rows having 'x' in xml column. So please tell me why does it happen?where i am going wrong?Also please correct it.

Also i have another problem where below query for the same above xml does not return any output.I expect it to return xml column having 'xyz' anywhere in it.So please have a look at it also and correct my errors.

```
DECLARE @id varchar 
SELECT @id = 'xyz'  
SELECT  *   
FROM    @tbl t1 
WHERE t1.col.exist('//*[text()=sql:variable("@id")]')=1
```

Comment: Please read the following blog: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not specified the length of `@id`. Using only `varchar` will in this case give you a length of one so the content of `@id` will be `x`.

Your first query checks for nodes that contain `x` and that matches all rows. The second query checks for nodes that has `x` as value and no row has that.

Change the declaration of `@id` to `DECLARE @id varchar(3)` and everything will work as expected.

Comment: Ok.But the @id may have any number of characters in my case so how it can be handled.Should i use varchar(max)?

Comment: @ITresearcher Unless it is enough with a `varchar(63)` you can use `varchar(max)`.

Comment: @ITresearcher why would you need the [@id] variable / the [user] node being varchar(max)? Do you really want to search in the XMLs by a key that can be up to 2 GB large (max)? What's the real size for your data there?